# Select number of closed ticket in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, join, count

I'm new in mysql and php. I want to count the numbers and get the sum of closed ticket each date. I need to get the right queries of counting and adding of closed ticket. I'm very much appreciated of your help. Thanks

Here's my queries:

```sql
 SELECT ticket.tn, ticket.id, MAX(ticket_history.change_time) AS closed
 FROM ticket_history
 LEFT JOIN ticket_history_type ON (ticket_history_type.id = ticket_history.history_type_id)
 LEFT JOIN ticket ON (ticket.id = ticket_history.ticket_id)
 LEFT JOIN ticket_state ON (ticket_state.id = ticket_history.state_id)
 LEFT JOIN ticket_state_type ON (ticket_state_type.id = ticket_state.type_id)
 WHERE ticket_history_type.name = "StateUpdate" AND ticket_state_type.name="closed"
 GROUP BY ticket.tn;
```

Here's the output:

tn                |    id         |    closed

2010080210123456  |    1          |    2013-10-21 09:45:43
.
.
.
.
.

And here's my queries for counting the closed

```
SELECT case when (select count(*) from ticket_history where ticket.tn, ticket.id,
MAX(ticket_history.change_time) AS closed
FROM ticket_history
LEFT JOIN ticket_history_type ON (ticket_history_type.id = ticket_history.history_type_id)
LEFT JOIN ticket ON (ticket.id = ticket_history.ticket_id)
LEFT JOIN ticket_state ON (ticket_state.id = ticket_history.state_id)
LEFT JOIN ticket_state_type ON (ticket_state_type.id = ticket_state.type_id)
WHERE ticket_history_type.name = "StateUpdate" AND ticket_state_type.name="closed"
GROUP BY ticket.tn;
```

Comment: Is that your whole query?

Comment: Mismatched parentheses? Lose the "select case when(" and get the inner select working.

Comment: Consider to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19897731/edit) your question and add table schemas, sample data, explain exactly what represents a closed ticket (is it just `ticket_state_type.name='closed'` or anything else)...